# Функция strpos поиск массива по переменной

Tags: php

Есть IF условие:

```
(strpos($text, $find) !== false)
```

Которое ищет в переменной $text переменную $find
Как можно сделать так, что бы он искал все слова из массива $find
Не копируя данную функцию по несколько раз.

Answer (score 0):

Можно циклом перебирать каждое слово:

```
$haveWords = false;
foreach ($find as $word) {
  if ((strpos($text, $word) !== false) {
    $haveWords = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Можно использовать регулярку:

```
$string = "привет мир!";
$words = [
    'привет',
    'картон'
];

$wordsString = implode('|', $words);
if (preg_match("/($wordsString)/", $string)) {
    echo "есть";
} else {
    echo "нет";
}
```

Comment: preg_grep() наверное лучше подходит для этой задачи, т.к. она умеет работать с массивами, и вам не понадобится его преобразование к строке.

Comment: @Эдуард grep принимает один шаблон, и массив для проверки, а тут наоборот массив шаблонов и строка для поиска

Comment: @teran и действительно - куда мои глаза смотрят :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант `array_reduce`

```
$haystack = "sample text string";
$needle = ['sample', 'text'];


$searchResult = array_reduce($needle, function($c, $item) use ($haystack){                        
                    return $c || strpos($haystack, $item) !== false; 
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю ещё вариант с сохранением найденных элементов в массив:

```
$string = 'sample text string';

preg_replace_callback(
    ['~sample~', '~text~'],
    function ($m)use(&$result) {
        $result[] = $m[0];
    },
    $string
);

var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "sample"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "text"
}
```

[Демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d4b129eea790665f15105a0372cc6243f78e10a)